# How to create this complex (for me) table in latex

Tags: latex

How can I recreate this table in latex? I didn't want to create a simple document in Word for my documentation and I'm trying my hand.
For now I have trivially solved the problem by integrating this table as a png.

[image: Cockburn table]

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: Please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html Do you really want to inflict such a table on your readers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Here is a sample based on your query:
[Sample table LaTeX code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypHIf.png)

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
use case \#6                 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Aggiungi} \\
                             & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}         \\
                             & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}         \\
                             & \multicolumn{3}{l}{}         \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Description} & Step  & Iscritto  & Sistema  \\
                             &       &           &         
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|p{.2\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.33\textwidth}|p{.33\textwidth}|}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!20}\textbf{Use} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor{blue!20}Aggiungi}\\\hline
Goal                            & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente}\\\hline
Pre                             & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente}\\\hline
Success                         & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente}\\\hline
Failed                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente}\\\hline
Primary                         & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Iscritto}\\\hline
Trigger                         & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{L'utente}\\\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Description}    & \cellcolor{blue!20}Step & \cellcolor{blue!20}Iscritto & \cellcolor{blue!20}Sistema\\\cline{2-4}
                                & 1                       & Preme                       & \\\cline{2-4}
                                & 2                       &                             & Mostra\\\cline{2-4}
                                & 3                       & Seleziona                   & \\\cline{2-4}
                                & 4                       &                             & Mostra\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{.19\textwidth}{Extension \#1\\ blah blah}} %
                                & \cellcolor{blue!20}Step     & \cellcolor{blue!20}Iscritto  & \cellcolor{blue!20}Sistema\\\cline{2-4}
                                & In un qual\-sia\-si pun\-to & 2                            & 3\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{.19\textwidth}{Extension \#1\\ blah blah}} %
                                & \cellcolor{blue!20}Step     & \cellcolor{blue!20}Iscritto  & \cellcolor{blue!20}Sistema\\\cline{2-4}
                                & 1                           & 2                            & 3\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{.19\textwidth}{Extension \#1\\ blah blah}} %
                                & \cellcolor{blue!20}Step     & \cellcolor{blue!20}Iscritto  & \cellcolor{blue!20}Sistema\\\cline{2-4}
                                & 1                           & 2                            & 3\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Check the two package in the header, needed to run.

You can also implement sans serif font, if you want.

This is the output of the above code:

[image: table]